# ScrollView does not work when wrapped in View

Tags: react-native

I have a component kind of like this

```
<ScrollView>
  <Text>Hello World</Text>
  <Text>Hello World</Text>
  <Text>Hello World</Text>
  <Text>Hello World</Text>
   ...
</ScrollView>
```

and it works just fine. But if I wrap it in a view like this:

```
<View>
  <ScrollView>
    <Text>Hello World</Text>
    <Text>Hello World</Text>
    <Text>Hello World</Text>
    <Text>Hello World</Text>
     ...
  </ScrollView>
</View>
```

suddenly, it doesn't scroll. If I inspect one of the texts, it doesn't even show that it's wrapped in a scrollview. I have no idea what could cause this. Only tested on Android.

Comment: Try adding flex: 1 to the view component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The View component that is wrapping ScrollView has to have set height or flex: 1.

In short add `flex: 1` or `height: 50 // any number will do` to View component